# How to calculate CTC loss of a sequence with all blanks using tf.nn.ctc_loss?

Tags: tensorflow

It is straightforward to calculate CTC loss of a sequence with all blanks by hand. But, I do not find a way to do this using [`tf.nn.ctc_loss` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss). Do I miss something, or `tf.nn.ctc_loss` implementation lacks this feature? This feature is necessary when a few sequences in the batch have no output symbol.

[I reported this on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13457), and it is closed with no answer.

Environments: tf version 1.3, CPU version; python 3.5/3.6; Win10/Ubuntu 16.04.

To begin with, we start from code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
num_classes, batch_size, seq_len = 3, 1, 2
labels = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0]], values=[0], dense_shape=[1,1])
inputs = tf.zeros([seq_len, batch_size, num_classes])
loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels, inputs, [seq_len])
print(tf.InteractiveSession().run(loss))
```

`tf.nn.ctc_loss` behaves as expected, and print the correct answer: 1.09861231

#### Issue one:

How to calculate the ctc loss of a sequence with all blanks? The tf.nn.ctc_loss API requires that values < num_labels, so we have no way to achieve it? If I do change the values in the above example to num_classes - 1 (the reserved blank ID), tf.nn.ctc_loss has no complain, and returns the wrong answer: 0.81093025! The correct answer is 2*log(3). The code to reproduce issue one is as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
num_classes, batch_size, seq_len = 3, 1, 2
labels = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0]], values=[2], dense_shape=[1,1])
inputs = tf.zeros([seq_len, batch_size, num_classes])
loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels, inputs, [seq_len])
print(tf.InteractiveSession().run(loss))
```

#### Issue two:

Let's change the sequence length to 1 as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
num_classes, batch_size, seq_len = 3, 1, 1
labels = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0]], values=[2], dense_shape=[1,1])
inputs = tf.zeros([seq_len, batch_size, num_classes])
loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels, inputs, [seq_len])
print(tf.InteractiveSession().run(loss))
```

and run the code again. This code gives the correct answer, log(3), in Ubuntu, but crashes in Win10 with message: Kernel died, restarting.

Comment: Can you file bugs for this with TensorFlow issues on GitHub?  Unfortunately bug fixes to the CTC op are not super high priority right now but will see if we can find someone to fix this in December.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TF v1.3 but in TF v2.0 CTC loss of a sequence with all blanks can be computed by using dense tensors instead of sparse. In TF v1.x there is ctc_loss_v2 which I believe has same behavior.

```
y_true = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])
y_pred = np.zeros((1, 2, 3), np.float32)
input_length = np.array([2])
label_length = np.array([0])
cost = tf.nn.ctc_loss(y_true, y_pred, label_length, input_length)
```